# How to read a file content on React Native ? // react-native-fs not working

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, react-native-fs

I am currently working on a react-native application that is asking the user to pick a text file from its phone and read it, I already implemented the part that ask the user to choose a file using `expo-document-picker` but I cannot manage to read the file content.

I already try using `react-native-fs` without any success :

```
            const content = async (file_path) => {
                let response = undefined;
                try {
                    response = await RNFS.readFile(path);
                } catch (err) {
                    showAlert("Failed to read file")
                    throw err;
    
                }
                return response;
            }
```

All I get is the following error :

`null is not an object (evaluating RNFSManager.RNFSFileTypeRegular)`

At this point I have read every issues and stackOverflow post related to the problem but the suggested solutions like `npm install --save react-native-fs`or reseting the cache does not work.

Perhaps it is because I use expo ? How can I read a file whitout react-native-fs ?

edit : I already tried to use *FileSystem* with the function `readAsStringAsync` but it always return the following :  `{"_U":0, "_V":0, "_W": null, "_X": null}"`

I appreciate the help !

Comment: I don't think you can use that package with Expo, only bare native React Native. This is an alternative for Expo: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/

Comment: I tried already readAsStringAsync from FileSystem always return an empty object like "{"_U":0, "_V":0, "_W": null, "_X": null}"

Comment: It's returning a promise.  Either use the .then() or .promise() to see actual result.